# Dapper performance results seem very similar on my machine

Tags: c#, performance, dapper

I ran the performance tests that came with the dapper source code: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

For the most part, the performance between the various data access methods were very very similiar, my results were in the 1200ms to 1500ms range.

Not sure what kind of server the results were done on, but their webpage shows results in the 50ms range.

I ran this in a i7 desktop with 12gb ram, was there something I should have done?  It seems to be running everything against the sql server's tempdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably compiling your code in Debug mode instead of Release mode, or using the Debugger (`Start Debugging F5` instead of `Start Without the Debugging Shift-F5`)